# get FormController whit variable name attribute

Tags: angularjs

when i use variable name at the form and name attribute is not specified, 
the form controller is not published on the current scope under this name.
how i can get  FormController?

```
<form name="{{'myForm'}}" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input name="input" required>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for having the form name as a variable? Can you point out the use case?

Comment: yes i can use variable for example => ng-init="**N='myForm'**"

Comment: What I meant was, why do you need the form name as a variable? Why cant it be a predefined value?

Comment: I have too many FORM  and i try to understanding all of the containg forms are valid.

**<form ng-repeat="Q in FORMS" name="{{Q.name}}">**

Comment: **solution**: http://plnkr.co/edit/nDDXWw?p=preview

Comment: @mehrad how will I be able to access the 'innerForm' in my controller?